# Generate crosstabulations from dataframe of categorical variables in survey

Tags: r, dataframe, crosstab

I've got some survey results and am trying to do some basic cross tabulations.  Each  column is a type of chemical, and the number 0:5 are how useful they were.

I'm trying to figure out a nice table that presents the freq, and percent.  Using table, or xtabs, I'm able to get individual results for each column, but I'd like to figure out a way to create a nice table that I'll be able to output into Latex that includes all the chemicals on one table.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Data Frame :

```
df <- read.table(text = "   
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
1  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3   0  0  0  0  0  0 NA
4  NA NA NA NA NA NA  5
5   0  0  0  0  0  2  0
6  NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA
7   0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8  NA NA NA NA NA  3 NA
9  NA  2 NA NA NA  3 NA
10 NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA
11  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
13  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
14 NA NA NA NA NA  2  3
15 NA  3 NA  3 NA NA NA
16 NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA
17  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
18 NA  5 NA  5 NA NA NA
19  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
20 NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA", header = T)
```

Desired Output (Accurate numbers for V1 and V2) :

```
                     V1            V2           etc....
                  Freq Percent   Freq Percent
No                 9     100       9    56.2
Poor               0      0        1    6.2 
Somewhat effective 0      0        1    6.2
Good               0      0        1    6.2
Very Good          0      0        3    18.75
NA                 0      0        1    6.2
```

Comment: @Amstell What is the cut-off limit for these classification?

Comment: @Ujjwal I created a small subset, so please see the data frame section of the post for the data.

Comment: @akrun what do you mean by cut off limit?  The numbers go from 0 to 5, with 0 being no

Comment: @Amstell I thought you had values that go from a range, and classified as good, if it falls betweeen x and y values.

Comment: @akrun sorry if it seemed unclear.  0=no, 1=poor, 2=somewhat effective, etc....

Comment: @Amstell In the first column, you have some NA's.  So, how do you get 0 for `V1` in the NA?

Comment: @akrun yeah that seems a bit unclear....5 = NA, but NA in the columns represents a no response....I only want those NA, which were chosen (5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, we are getting the frequency for each column by using `lapply` and `table`.  `lapply` gets the `data.frame` in a `list` environment and then use `table` after converting the column to `factor` with levels specified as `0:5`.  Use, `prop.table` to get the proportion, `cbind` the `Freq` and `Percent`, convert the `list` to `data.frame` by `do.call(cbind`, and finally rename the `row.names` and `colnames`

```
  res <-  do.call(cbind,lapply(df, function(x) {
            x1 <- table(factor(x, levels=0:5,
               labels=c('No', 'Poor', 'Somewhat Effective', 
                               'Good', 'Very Good', 'NA') ))
             cbind(Freq=x1, Percent=round(100*prop.table(x1),2))}))
 colnames(res) <- paste(rep(paste0('V',1:7),each=2),
                                     colnames(res),sep=".")

  head(res,2)
  #     V1.Freq V1.Percent V2.Freq V2.Percent V3.Freq V3.Percent V4.Freq
  #No         9        100       9      56.25       9        100       9
  #Poor       0          0       1       6.25       0          0       0
  #     V4.Percent V5.Freq V5.Percent V6.Freq V6.Percent V7.Freq V7.Percent
  #No        81.82       9        100       8      66.67       8         80
  #Poor       0.00       0          0       0       0.00       0          0
```

Comment: This did it thank you....If possible could you please explain the first part that has the function....not quite sure what it is doing.  thanks!

Comment: thank you so much for your help....never would have thought to go this route, but it's great to learn..  thanks again

Comment: @AnandaMahto  Thanks, I did ask the OP about it.  I think I can use the `labels` in `factor` (as you did) and remove the `useNA` from `table`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a regular "dplyr" or "tidyr" user, so I'm not sure if this is the best approach using those tools (but it seems to work):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  gather(var, val, V1:V7) %>%             ## Make the data long
  na.omit() %>%                           ## We don't need the NAs
  ## Factor the "value" column
  mutate(val = factor(val, 0:5, c("No", "Poor", "Somewhat Effective", 
                                  "Good", "Very Good", "NA"))) %>%
  group_by(val, var) %>%                  ## Group by val and var
  summarise(Freq = n()) %>%               ## Get the count
  group_by(var) %>%                       ## Group just by var now
  mutate(Pct = Freq/sum(Freq) * 100) %>%  ## Calculate the percent
  gather(R1, R2, Freq:Pct) %>%            ## Go long again....
  unite(Var, var, R1) %>%                 ## Combine the var and R1 cols
  spread(Var, R2, fill = 0)               ## Go wide....
# Source: local data frame [6 x 15]
# 
#                  val V1_Freq V1_Pct V2_Freq V2_Pct V3_Freq V3_Pct V4_Freq
# 1                 No       9    100       9  56.25       9    100       9
# 2               Poor       0      0       1   6.25       0      0       0
# 3 Somewhat Effective       0      0       1   6.25       0      0       0
# 4               Good       0      0       1   6.25       0      0       1
# 5          Very Good       0      0       3  18.75       0      0       0
# 6                 NA       0      0       1   6.25       0      0       1
# Variables not shown: V4_Pct (dbl), V5_Freq (dbl), V5_Pct (dbl), V6_Freq
#   (dbl), V6_Pct (dbl), V7_Freq (dbl), V7_Pct (dbl)
```

---

The "data.table" approach is similar in terms of the series of steps you'll have to go through.

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
levs <- c("No", "Poor", "Somewhat Effective", "Good", "Very Good", "NA")
DT <- melt(as.data.table(df, keep.rownames = TRUE), 
           id.vars = "rn", na.rm = TRUE)
DT <- DT[, value := factor(value, 0:5, levs)
         ][, list(Freq = .N), by = list(variable, value) 
           ][, Pct := Freq/sum(Freq) * 100, by = list(variable)]
dcast.data.table(melt(DT, id.vars = c("variable", "value")),
                 value ~ variable + variable.1, 
                 value.var = "value.1", fill = 0)
```

---

OK, one more... (a variant on @akrun's answer)

```
library(gdata)      ## For "interleave"
levs <- c("No", "Poor", "Somewhat Effective", "Good", "Very Good", "NA")
x1 <- sapply(lapply(df, factor, 0:5, levs), table)
t(interleave(t(x1), t(prop.table(x1, 2))))

### Or, skipping the transposing....
## library(SOfun)   ## For "Riffle" which is like "interleave"
## Riffle(x1, prop.table(x1, 2) * 100)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was wondering how to do this in dplyr and tidyr.....I'll look at this carefully

Comment: @AnandaMahto  Thanks for the pointer.  I did changed the output.  Now, I guess it is consistent. (+1) for the `dplyr`